Spark application running on AWS EMR throws error "this.fileSystem" is null while writing to hudi
We have a spark application running on aws emr, which computes results, but while writing to hudi it throws up below error. And also not sure if it is while writing to hudi or executing at the end(but most of the computations gets completed and logs correctly)
Spark version: 3.4, Hudi version: 0.14
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)" because "this.fileSystem" is null
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.open(EmrFileSystem.java:197) ~[emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.60.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hudi.common.fs.HoodieWrapperFileSystem.open(HoodieWrapperFileSystem.java:476) ~[__app__.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.timeline.HoodieActiveTimeline.readDataFromPath(HoodieActiveTimeline.java:800) ~[__app__.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.timeline.HoodieActiveTimeline.getInstantDetails(HoodieActiveTimeline.java:310) ~[__app__.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hudi.common.table.timeline.HoodieDefaultTimeline.getInstantDetails(HoodieDefaultTimeline.java:495) ~[__app__.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hudi.IncrementalRelation.$anonfun$buildScan$4(IncrementalRelation.scala:168) ~[__app__.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hudi.IncrementalRelation.buildScan(IncrementalRelation.scala:167) ~[__app__.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:383) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$1(QueryPlanner.scala:63) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:73) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$3(QueryPlanner.scala:78) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$folder$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:196) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$folder$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:194) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:199) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:192) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: [INTERNAL_ERROR] The Spark SQL phase planning failed with an internal error. You hit a bug in Spark or the Spark plugins you use. Please, report this bug to the corresponding communities or vendors, and provide the full stack trace.
    at org.apache.spark.SparkException$.internalError(SparkException.scala:88) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.toInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:560) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:572) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:231) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:230) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:171) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:164) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.1-amzn-2.jar:3.4.1-amzn-2]

